# Using &nbsp; in Visual Studio 10 ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, whitespace

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition for developing an application in ASP.NET MVC3 framework.

I have come across a situation where I need to have a literal space character, usually accomplished by adding `&nbsp;` (something similar) in HTML.

However, program gives a run-time error.

How do I overcome this?

Code:

```
<div class="week">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        <div class="day">
            @weekStartDay.ToString().Substring(0, 3)
        </div>            
&nbsp;
       weekStartDay = (DayOfWeek)(((int)weekStartDay + 1) % 7);
    }
</div>
```

Error:

c:***\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Views\Home\Calendar.cshtml(22): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change your code to

```
<div class="week">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        <div class="day">
            @weekStartDay.ToString().Substring(0, 3)
        </div>            
       @:&nbsp;
       weekStartDay = (DayOfWeek)(((int)weekStartDay + 1) % 7);
    }
</div>
```

@: tells the Razor view engine `&nbsp;` is plain text

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this code in Visual Studio 2012 you will see the exact same error message. The   is underlined and the tooltip shows this message.

The problem is that you are inside a code block: `@{ }`. If you want to output plain text you have to wrap it inside an HTML element like this:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

or you have to use

```
@:&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use add @: before &nbsp

Answer (score 1):

for every list item in your dropdown list you have to replace your list item value by  `.Replace(" ", "\u00A0")`

eg:

---

**in your  controller**

```
 var Listval =(from u in yourtablename select u.YourColumnName.Replace(" ", "\u00A0")).Distinct().ToList();
  ViewBag.DDlVals= new SelectList(Listval);
```

---

**in your View page**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourColumnName, (SelectList)ViewBag.DDlVals, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```